# How to Remove "Others" from the login page

Tags: macos, big-sur, vmware

[image: Print Screen]

Hi, I turned on my pc today and I was surprised by the screen I got.

I can't log in with my user because I have the only one. The main user in the case.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Why did you tag this with VMware?

Comment: Because iOS is running on VMWare

Comment: That looks like macOS not iOS. What OS is underneath it & what version of VMWare. That Other is presented would normally have been configured before the last reboot & you should be able to login by clicking it them presenting any valid credentials. There's a possibility it's being presented because the default user account can't be found, in which case you need to try boot to recovery.

Comment: See https://www.alphr.com/mac-vm-boot-recovery-mode-vmware-fusion/